# MongoExecutionTimeoutException/MongoDb C# linq API

Tags: mongodb, linq, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Using the [C# linq API](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/linq/) against a MongoDb server, I need to increase a timeout to avoid getting the [MongoExecutionTimeoutException](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/1.11/html/1dfdb9f0-d8fe-1fec-c50f-5e49326d02e3.htm) exception. However I an unable to find a timeout property for that both on query level and client level.

Tried this:

```
        var aggregateOptions = new AggregateOptions();
        aggregateOptions.MaxTime = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        aggregateOptions.MaxAwaitTime = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        aggregateOptions.UseCursor = true;

        var testQuery = testCollection.AsQueryable(aggregateOptions)
          .Something...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timeout on the cursor level. Please see documentation at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/